# Why no feature of promoting question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, bounty

When we ask a question only time it remains more active is during the initial phase. After some time the view for the question keeps on decreasing. Sometimes it is possible that a good quality receives no acceptable answer. But than as new questions are added the question keeps getting to bottom of unanswered questions and its possible that the question will be completely neglected in future so the user is likely to ask the same question again and that question will than be tagged as duplicate.

Why can't SO implement a feature where user can spend their reputation to make their question on top again for some time. So chances of it getting answered again will improve.

Comment: You mean like a bounty?

Comment: I am thinking in way of promoting the question targeting  top users

Comment: There is a feature called bounties that does exactly what you propose - except for the targeting of specific users. That would be a major annoyance and isn't going to happen.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: Also see [How could I notify Stack Overflow's expert users about my new question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/how-could-i-notify-stack-overflows-expert-users-about-my-new-question) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12):

### SO has actually implemented it. They call it bounty.

By providing a bounty to a question, you are giving the question, some of your reps, which will go to the answerer if you like his answer.

By giving  bounty to a question, you are making the question appear in `"Featured tab"`.

You'll need 75 reps to give a bounty. The minimum bounty allowed is 50 and the maximum is 500.

You can target specific users by tagging your question right.